# optimised minimum value using findall/3

Tags: optimization, prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I am trying to optimise and find the minimum Cost of a function. The program below uses `findall/3` to iterate over all possible options of values which are generated from using the `clpfd` library provided by SWI-Prolog.

There are several `Cost` values that are generated using this program below which are gathered into a list. I know that in order to get the minimum value I can simply use the `min_list/2` predicate available. However, what I want is that once the program finds a certain value, which is currently the minimum, while computing other options, if the value turns out to be greater than the minimum value, its not added the list.

So essentially, I want to optimise the program so that it simply accounts for the minimum value generated by the program.

```
optimise(input, arguments, Cost):-
    findall(Cost, some_predicate(input, arguments, Cost), List).

some_predicate(input, arguments, Cost):-
    Option in input..arguments, label(Option),
    find_data(Option, Value),
    find_cost(Value, Cost).
```

The above code has been modified so that it is condensed and but fulfils the purpose of the question.

Comment: What *is* the question?

Comment: Like it says - "optimise the program so that it simply accounts for the minimum value generated by the program"

Answer (score 0):

I think that findall it's not the right tool: [here](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/blob/master/lag.pl) is some code I wrote time ago, that could help you. For instance, given

```
member_(X,Y) :- member(Y,X).
```

we can get the lower element

```
?- integrate(min, member_([1,2,4,-3]), M).
M = -3
```

I applied the usual convention to postfix with underscore a library predicate that swaps arguments, to be able to meta call it.

Just take that code as an example, paying attention to [nb_setarg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setarg/3) usage.

To see if it could work 'out-of-the-box', try:

```
:- [lag].

optimise(Input, Arguments, Cost):-
    integrate(min, some_predicate(Input, Arguments), Cost).
```

Comment: Thanks for that information, however, i don't *just* want the lower element, i want to optimise it for to find the minimum, as it needs be calculated using a cost funciton

Comment: Maybe you're missing the point: some_predicate will be called until it fails, *exactly* as does findall/3. integrate/3 it's (better, will be) a *space saving* replacement.